# Nested forms - show only *some* children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

In a form, a company can edit both its own details and the details of a new project. In my nested form, I have:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @company ... do |form| %>
  <%= form.inputs do %>
    <%= form.input :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.inputs :for => :projects do |p| %> 
    <%= %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the thing: I only want details to be shown for **a new project** / projects, not every project the company has. If the company has 5 projects and my controller includes `@company.projects.build`, I get 6 instead of 1.

How can I build this form so we only have to deal with a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question well but I'll answer and correct me if I misunderstood:

```
  <%= form.inputs :for => projects do |p| %> 
    <% if p.object.new_record? %>
       <%= %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I'm sorry Erez - please see the new corrected code in my question. I tried putting `@project` instead of `:projects` but the controller didn't save the form's inputs, saying that the attribute 'project' is missing. The form as it is in my question works fine, but I just want to deal with one new project and not all the old ones.